# BOD in WebsphereCommerce Version 7

Tags: websphere-7

Can anyone explain in detail about BOD in websphere commerce?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow the tutorial in the below link to understand how the different classes are linked and what coding has to be done for the different classes for the various processes like get, process, change and sync of the BOD.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.management-center_customization.doc/tutorial/ttf_svcmain.htm